# Android to Bada

Tags: android, bada

Is it possible to convert my Android app to Bada Os?

Do you know any converter or anything else or should be written Bada Sdk again?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Currently it is impossible to port Bada applications on Android and vise-versa but there are few exceptions.

1. If you are making widgets for Bada
   OS, then you can strait away run it
   on Samsung's Android devices. (with
   minor packaging modifications)
2. You can straight away port code you
   have written in Android's NDK to
   Bada... but that would be limited to
   libs only (not anything GUI)
3. If you are a game developer, I
   suggest you to use Air Play SDK, you
   can port Android to Bada and vise
   versa with few clicks.

Comment: +1 for (2) porting libs (not anything GUI). A universal truth, how refreshing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're suggesting a tool to automatically port it over. It should be written again. There isn't anything available that would effectively automatically port it over. Android applications are written in primarily Java, Bada is C++. Not to mention the API differences. It should be written again, both systems have different ways of doing things. Port it over to an equivalent app.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much Android, Bada is based on C++ with a unique set of non-STL collection classes and a custom approach to object instantiation (even within the C++ realm). I'd expect a rewrite to be necessary.

Comment: Bada supports STL library : http://dpimg.ospos.net/contents/docs/resources_1.1.0/com.osp.apireference.help/group__CplusplusSTL.html.
It is possible to share C/C++ code between Bada SDK and Android NDK.

Comment: But none of the built-in platform libraries use the STL classes. Bada-specific collections, etc are provided and used internally.